On mollifiers acting between $L^2$ and Sobolev spaces
(I'm reposting here this question from MSE as it didn't receive any answer for two weeks.)
Consider a sequence of finite lattices in $\mathbb{R}^n$ defined by
$$L_k= [-k,k]^n \cap 2^{-k}\cdot \mathbb{Z}^n, \quad k=1,2,3,\ldots$$
Write $H^s(\mathbb{R}^n)$ for the Sobolev space of exponent $s$ and fix $s>n/2$ so that $H^s(\mathbb{R}^n)$ consists of continuous functions by the Sobolev embedding theorem. Define a sequence of decreasing closed subspaces of $H^s(\mathbb{R}^n)$ via
$$ S_k=\{ f \in  H^s(\mathbb{R}^n): f(x)=0 \,\,\forall  x \in L_k\}$$
so that $\cap_{k=1}^{\infty}S_k=\{0\}$. Then the sequence of orthogonal projections onto $S_k$ converges strongly to 0 in $H^s(\mathbb{R}^n)$.
My question is: is it possible to find a sequence of mollifiers
$$J_k: L^2(\mathbb{R}^n) \rightarrow  H^s(\mathbb{R}^n)$$ such that the orthogonal projections onto the preimages $J_k^{-1}(S_k)$ converge strongly to 0 in $L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$ ?
Note: by a sequence of mollifiers I mean a sequence of operators given by convolution with a sequence of smooth compactly supported functions tending weakly to a delta function.
EDIT: here is a reason why I think the above is plausible. If one considers the mollifiers as operators acting on $H^s(\mathbb{R}^n)$, then they can be taken to be selfadjoint and the analogous statement about the orthogonal projections onto the preimages (which are now in $H^s(\mathbb{R}^n)$) follows from the Proposition in this answer.

I am not sure to understand your question. $S_k$ is an orthogonal projection w.r.t. $H^s(\mathbb{R}^n)$ topology, right ? So what does exactly mean "orthogonal projections onto the preimages $J_k^{-1}(S_k)$ ? " ?

@AymanMoussa : The preimages $J_k^{-1}(S_k)$ are closed subspaces of the Hilbert space $L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$, hence one can consider the corresponding orthogonal projections.
